# How do I make sure that all rows with the same foreign key have unique names in my PostgreSQL database?

Tags: sql, postgresql, create-table, unique-constraint, alter-table

I have a PostgreSQL database with two tables: `Team` and `Project`, in a one-to-many relationship.

Team has these columns:

- id
- name

Project has these:

- id
- name
- team_id

**I'd like to make sure that the projects *within a team* must have unique names.**

Projects belonging to different teams should be able to share names without a problem, so `UNIQUE` doesn't really help.

It seems like I might be able to use a custom `CHECK` constraint to do this, but failing that, what would be a sensible, declarative way to implement it in javascript?

I'm using [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/) to interact with my database, and elsewhere in my app I'm using [Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) to validate the schemas of objects. Perhaps I could combine these somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a unique constraint:

```
alter table project add constraint unq_project_teamid_name
    unique (team_id, name);
```

You can also do this with a unique index:

```
create unique index unq_project_teamid_name on project(team_id, name);
```

Comment: so simple! totally missed that it's possible to have a unique constraint across more than one column

Answer (score 0):

You can use a compound unique key:

```
create table project (
    id serial primary key,
    name text,
    team_id int references team(id),
    unique (team_id, name)
);
```

Or if you want to add it to an existing table:

```
alter table project 
    add constraint cs_project_uniq_name_team 
    unique(team_id, name)
;
```